# search is not working in Arraylist due to case sensitivity

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, search, arraylist

- I have created an **Address** class*

```
public class Address {
    
    
    private long id;
    private String organizationName;
    private long entId;
    private String orgAddress;
    private String orgType;

    }
```

And I have **created a list** which have Address objects inside and i have created an **Api** using it.

```
List<Address> list;
    
    
    
    public AddressServiceImpl() {
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Address(1,"Anth",123456,"Time square,NY","Doctor"));
        list.add(new Address(2,"carl",12114,"street 16,NY","Staff"));
    }
```

and now i need to **search a part of string** from the list now and i want to fetch the objects that have **organizationName **as the related String

```
@Override
    public List<Address> searchAddress(String search) { 
        
        List<Address> listClone= new ArrayList<>();
        for(Address d : list){
            if(d.getOrganizationName().toLowerCase() != null && d.getOrganizationName().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
               listClone.add(d);
        }
            
            
        }
        return listClone;
    

    }
```

But when i am **searching "Anth" and "anth"** it is not giving any response.**Please Help!!!**

But when i am **searching "Anth" and "anth"** it is not giving any response.**Please Help!!!**

Comment: you should first look at your current code: if ( d.getOrganizationName().toLowerCase() != null ... ) -> can you spot the serious problem here? that line can not possibly return null, it can, however, throw a NullPointerException

Comment: As for your comparison, don't use "contains", but use equalsIgnoreCase instead

Comment: And the second condition misses the toLowerCase() after getOrganizationalname()

Comment: @Stultuske OP needs to "search a part of string", so `contains` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code

```
   if(d.getOrganizationName().toLowerCase() != null 
      && d.getOrganizationName().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
          listClone.add(d);
   }
```

Two issues here:

- your null check is bad. If `d.getOrganizationName()` is `null` (which can apparently happen), calling `toLowerCase` on it will throw a `NullPointerException`.
- your other part of the check uses `contains`, but you don't use `toLowerCase` on it.

What you want is

```
   if(d.getOrganizationName() != null
      && d.getOrganizationName().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
        listClone.add(d);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just miss toLower() in d.getOrganizationName() .

public static List searchAddress(String search) {

```
    List<Address> listClone = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Address d : AddressServiceImpl()) {
        if (d.getOrganizationName() != null
                && d.getOrganizationName().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
            listClone.add(d);
        }

    }
    return listClone;

}
```